# jQuery clone() Meta Title / document.title

Tags: jquery, clone, title, meta-tags, appendto

Can one use jQuery to `clone()` a meta title?  Basically I am trying to grab the Meta Tag Title and put it at the end of some words such as "Related Products for...", "Accessories for...".  Below doesn't work but is in for example.

ie:

```
$('document.title').clone().appendTo('#similar, #suggested');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in appending the string, why not just use `document.title`?

```
$('#similar, #suggested').append( document.title );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Uyfae/

Comment: Bingo that worked, it appears as though clone() is only when working with DOM elements.

Comment: @ToddN: `title` is a DOM element, but I'd imagine that it is only allowed in the `head`. Anyway, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the value this way

```
$("head title").text();
```

Comment: You are right it works as an alert, however I cannot get it to work with clone() yet, im guessing clone() only works with elements in the DOM?

Comment: `text()` just returns the value. You don't need to `clone()`